# Can someone show me how to assign some values from a data frame to null values of a certain column in another data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, isnull, fillna

I have an array of prediction data, processed from Linear Regression, and now I want to merge/insert the prediction data to the main data frame. My prediction data consists of 7 x 1 array, which is prediction for one of the main data frame's column. Here is [the bottom part of main data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0EV4.png), and here is [the array of prediction data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQlo0.png).

I've been thinking of some ways to solve this;

- using `fillna()` (since it's null values I want to change):

  ```
  #Not real code
  #df = main data frame
  #inv_y = array of prediction value
  df['Cart'].isnull().fillna(value=dict([(inv_y['Cart'].T)]), inplace=True)
  ```
- `iloc`,

  ```
  df['Cart'].iloc[[69,70,71,72,73,74,75]] = inv_y
  ```
- `loc` with `isnull`,

  ```
  b = inv_y.loc[~inv_y_['Cart'].isnull()]
  df.loc[df['Cart'].isnull(),['Cart']]=b
  ```
- `append` (I couldn't put the code here since I already deleted it),
- etc.

None of these worked out. When running these codes (and the other varieties that I don't put them here, just too much), the errors are always about dimensions or data type (whether the input should be `scalar`, `dict`, etc). For example, when using `fillna()`, the attribute error message is `'tuple' object has no attribute 'T'` so I transposed the array (and still it refused to work).

I'm really open to other suggestions of methods for the solution, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the data in the images as code instead (formatted with ```, same as the code blocks)? It would make it easier to copy-paste for creating an example, see [mcve]. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples